# using foreach to insert dynamic table inputs to mysql database didn't work

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a script which add new table rows by javascript, and I'm using `foreach` function to insert the table rows in mysql, the `foreach` function didn't insert the data for all rows that added dynamically with using add row button, the PHP function is insert one/first row for table only, as known first rows `<tr>td tags</tr>` its found on `html`, when loaded..

but Note when i add td tags rows manually in html foreach function worked correctly and insert all rows..
please i need help to insert all data in rows added dynamicaly from js..

this is html :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-bordered table-hover" data-name="cont-table">
    <thead style="">
       <tr>
        <th class="text-center"> m </th>
        <th class="text-center"> item </th>
        <th class="text-center"> unit </th>
        <th class="text-center"> quantity </th>
        <th class="text-center"> unit price </th>
        <th class="text-center"> financial years </th>
        <th class="text-center"> total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="snum">1.</span></td>
      <td>

        <select class="select" id="first_name" name="items[]">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td>

        <select class="select" id="last_name" name="units[]">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><input class="select qty" type="number" id="tamil" name="qtys[]"/></td>
      <td><input class="select unit" type="number" id="english" name="unitno[]" /></td>
      <td>
        <select class="select " id="computer" name="financials[]">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
        </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="total" name="totals[]" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button id="add_row"  type="button" class="delete btn btn-default pull-right">delete</button>
  <button id="add_row" style="margin-right:5px;" type="button" class="addmore btn btn-default pull-right">add row</button>

  <input name="set-cont" type="submit" class="sb-btn center" value="حفظ"/>
</form>
```

this is javascript for add rows:

```
$(".addmore").on('click',function(){
    count=$('table tr').length;
    var data="<tr><td><span id='snum"+i+"'>"+count+".</span></td>";
    data +="<td><select class='select' id='first_name' name='item[]'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td> <td><select class='select' id='last_name' name='unit[]'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td><td><input type='text'  class='select qty' id='tamil' name='qty[]'/></td><td><input type='text' class='select unit' id='english'  name='unitno[]'/></td><td><select class='select' id='computer' name='financial[]'><option>1</option><option>2</option></select></td><td><input type='text' class='amount' id='total' name='total[]'/></td></tr>";
    $('table').append(data);
    i++;
});
```

This is PHP code to insert data to mysql:

```
if(isset($_POST['set-cont'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['items'] as $key => $value)  {
        $items = $_POST["items"][$key];
        $units = $_POST["units"][$key];
        $qtys = $_POST["qtys"][$key];
        $unitno = $_POST["unitno"][$key];
        $financials = $_POST["financials"][$key];
        $totals = $_POST["totals"][$key];
        try {
            $db = DB();
            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table_contract (items, units, qtys, unitno, financials, totals) VALUES(:items,:units,:qtys,:unitno,:financials,:totals)");
            $query->bindParam("items", $items, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("units", $units, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("qtys", $qtys, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("unitno", $unitno, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("financials", $financials, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam("totals", $totals, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
           exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your JavaScript code is adding select fields with name='item[]'.  I think you want name='items[]'
2. You cant have multiple fields with the same id.  An id has to be unique.  That is, you can have two fields with id='first_name'